# How Do I Delete an Email from Content Builder Using REST API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email, content-builder, delete

I can create an email with the REST API but I do not know how to delete one and I cannot find any information about it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can delete using the Content Builder API and a delete method to this endpoint -
/asset/v1/content/assets/{id}

Details here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/content-api.htm